# Can a modern commercial passenger flight recover from failed sensor(s)?

Tags: navigation, ifr-navigation, sensors

ABC News reports a failure in a [pitot tube sensor](https://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/airbus-air-france-face-criminal-trial-rio-paris-91272464) may be the cause of an AirFrance Rio to Paris flight tragedy.  Excerpts from the news include:

> An Associated Press investigation at the time found that Airbus had
> known since at least 2002 about problems with the type of pitots used
> on the jet that crashed, but failed to replace them until after the
> crash.
>
> As a storm buffeted the plane, ice disabled the plane's pitot tubes,
> blocking speed and altitude information. The autopilot disconnected.
> The crew resumed manual piloting, but with erroneous navigation data.
> The plane went into an aerodynamic stall, its nose pitched upward and
> then it plunged into the sea on June 1, 2009.
>
> Air France is accused of not having implemented training in the event
> of icing of the pitot probes despite the risks. It has since changed
> its training manuals and simulations. The company said it would
> demonstrate in court “that it has not committed a criminal fault at
> the origin of the accident” and plead for acquittal.

If a pilot recognizes that flight condition sensor inputs (Altitude, AOA, etc) are faulty: what prevents the pilot from "dead reckoning" and safely land the aircraft at the nearest airstrip?

Comment: That happened 13 years ago. It has been discussed *quite* thoroughly here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=Af4447 Have you done *any* research? Is there any new development?

Comment: Additionally to AF447, there is [this A330 incident](https://avherald.com/h?article=4bb4f5b3) where all 3 airspeed inputs failed due to forgotten pitot covers. Mentour pilot did a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f80WwpNuaxg&ab_channel=MentourPilot) on it which might be of interest to you.

Comment: @nobody That search link returns nothing. Correct link is aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=Af447

Comment: Even the basic news report I saw recently said that this was due to pilot training and reactions, not just to a faulty sensor.

Comment: I strongly disagree that it was the failed sensor.  Failed sensors are just *slightly inconvenient*, but rarely a serious problem.  The real cause was the pilot's failure to respond appropriately by reading the other instruments, understanding the problem and taking appropriate action.  Also the other pilots' failure to monitor and oversee the handling of the plane.

Comment: Unfortunately not only the not-properly trained pilots but also the Human-Maschine-Interface played a role: the [final Bea report](http://bea.aero/docspa/2009/f-cp090601.en/pdf/f-cp090601.en.pdf) contains safety recommendations also on Ergonomics.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: Yes it can! (no pun intended)

This is done because all critical systems are built either such that they are very, *very* unlikely to fail. For flight critical systems it is required that the systems fails with a probability of only 1e-9 (therefore once every 1e9 flight hours), or in other words practically never. In case of electronics this usually means that they are built redundantly, meaning two or more copies of the hardware exist such that if one fails, the other can take over. For example critical flight computers onboard the [Airbus A320 or Boeing 777](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291857561_Dissimilar_redundant_flight_control_computer_system) which compute the control inputs for the control surfaces are redundant both in hardware and software such that one of the (two or more) flight control computers can fail without something bad happening.

A good counterexample is that of the [MCAS fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maneuvering_Characteristics_Augmentation_System) in which Boeing connected only *one* Angle-of-Attack probe to the flight control computers. Therefore any fail in this sensor had direct consequences for the flight controls, which is exactly what happend (twice...). This resulted in the death of 346 people.

This should illustrate two things:

1. It vividly shows that redudancy is very much needed for the safety (btw, this is one major reason why aviation is so expensive)
2. Coming back to your question: Yes the pilot is able to safely return to the airstrip with one sensor fail. For more then one sensor it depends a bit on the exact combination, but in all generality it still should work.